# How to parse String to Date with Talend in this format "Tue Feb 23 00:00:00 EST 2021"

Tags: date, parsing, talend

im trying to parse my String to Date but i got this error :

**Unparseable date: "Tue Feb 23 00:00:00 EST 2021"**

This is what i do :

[image]

The code in the expression builder is:

```
TalendDate.parseDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",row1.DAT_DEB_ACTIF)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: this comment might not be useful but FYI this same code is working in my studio.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your studio is installed on a machine with a non-english OS.

Try to force the locale to "english" with

```
TalendDate.parseDateLocale("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",  row1.DAT_DEB_ACTIF, "en")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :

```
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date(row1.DAT_DEB_ACTIF)))
```